# How to point a delegate to an extension method

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

```
public class UITestCtrl
{

}

public static class Ext
{
    public static void FindElement(this UITestCtrl clas)
    {
    }
}

public class Brwsr : UITestCtrl
{
    public void FindElement()
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to point delegate to extension method

```
private delegate void MyDell_();
MyDell_ dell = new MyDell_(Ext.FindElement());
```

I am getting error:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'clas' of 'Ext.FindElement(UITestCtrl)'

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Your extension method is simply a static method taking one parameter and returning void, 
// so an action is appropriate delegate signature:
Action<UITestCtrl> dell = Ext.FindElement;

UITestCtrl control = new UITestCtrl();

dell(control);// calling the extension method via the assigned delegate, passing the one parameter
```

Here's a console app where instead of UITestCtrl I have used a List:

```
static class Ext
{
    public static void FindElement(List<string> test)
    {
        test.Add("blah");
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<List<string>> dell = Ext.FindElement;

        var control = new List<string>();
        dell(control);// calling the extension method via the assigned delegate

    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you create a "closed" delegate, in which case the `this` argument is captured just like it is when creating a delegate from an instance and non-static method